# Displaying username with AmplifyGreetings

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have a react app being developed with the Amazon Amplify framework. As per the [documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/ui/auth/authenticator/q/framework/react#greetings) I am trying to retrieve my username (that I have specified during the signup process) before the `Signout` button. The document is not clearly instructed on how to display my username, as the `<AmplifyGreetings>` component puts a dummy attribute of username. Could someone guide me on how to do that?

Code:
App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { withAuthenticator, AmplifyGreetings } from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <AmplifyGreetings username="retrieve your username here"></AmplifyGreetings>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withAuthenticator(App);
```

This is what my output looks like.
[image]

Comment: refer to https://richardzcode.github.io/Journal-AWS-Amplify-Tutorial/step-02/#5-home-page-and-authstate and let me know if that is what you are looking for?

Comment: In general, yes, this is what I am looking for. But before it used to be very simple just by adding so: (App, {AmplifyGreetings: true}), which no longer works, as amplify docs clearly mentions they have Breaking changes for withAuthenticator. The github docs you have linked actually doesn't use any <AmplifyGreetings> component, moreover they are not using class component in React. So I wonder how would I implement the user greetings now in my project. I believe it should ve super simple by writing just 2 or 3 lines of codes.